# count banner impressions using java or javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I want to count banner impressions in my web page. For Example I have a image slider and I need to count how many times each image displayed in my page, And each individual image count  should have to save in the database.

I want write this in java or javascript

Can anyone Help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(function(){
   $('img').load(function(){
        $.post('update.php', {img: $(this).attr("id")});
   });
});
```

And in update.php you will get a post request with $_POST['img'] = Image-Id. Use it to update the count record in your database with +1.

Keep in mind this will create a new request to update.php for each image that is loaded.

PS: You need jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But i want this in java

Comment: You seem confused about what you want.  You need better requirements.  What have you got at the moment?

Comment: @user2618704 you said Java or Javascript :) Make up your mid.

Comment: Btw, this is javascript. Is just using the jQuery plugin.